# Applications of modular forms outside Number Theory?

Tags: soft-question

Are there applications of modular forms to areas other than Number Theory (and Galois Theory)  such as Combinatorics, Algebraic Topology, Algebraic Geometry, Theoretical Physics,...?

Comment: Yup.$ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: A related question has already been asked, with answers that (somewhat adequately) cover your question too:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24604/why-are-modular-forms-interesting

Comment: Googling "applications of modular forms" yields 329,000 hits.

Comment: That would be an ecumenical matter

Comment: Yoou might consult Sarnak's *Some Applications of Modular Forms*:
http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CRiAEnmE_DcC&lpg=PP1&ots=zVuG4Nca94&dq=modular%20forms%20sarnak&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Besides "real applications", there are some slightly odd ones in the high energy physics literature, like http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.4209 :)

Answer (score 1):

I am by no means an expert, in fact I don't *really* know what a modular form is! But yes.

Wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Modular_forms

or if you want more,

http://tinyurl.com/25unfrb

:)

You may want to try asking a more specific question if there's something you've been wondering about. Otherwise is seems a bit too vague to really address here.