# What are the applications of modular forms in number theory?

Tags: nt.number-theory, soft-question, modular-forms

I am new to the topic, so I'm trying to get an overview. I am aware of the relation between modular forms and $L$-series (but don't know what that does) and FLT.

Are there other applications of modular forms other than counting problems (by obtaining the coefficients of a series) in number theory?

A short list would be sufficient but a little more detail with that would be helpful.

EDIT:
I am aware of **[this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24604/why-are-modular-forms-interesting)** but my question is specifically on number theory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are modular forms interesting?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24604/why-are-modular-forms-interesting)

Comment: @consider non trivial cases I encourage you to read the book of Jan Bruiner the 123 Modular forms which contains all aplications of different types of modular forms here is the link: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-74119-0

Answer (score 10):

- [Fibonacci and
  Lucas Perfect Powers](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0403046)
  Modular forms are used to demonstrate that the only perfect powers in
  the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) are 0, 1, 8 and 144 and the only perfect
  powers in the [Lucas sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence) are 1 and 4.
- [The
  Lebesgue-Nagell equation](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405220)
  Modular forms are used to solve the [Lebesgue-Nagell equation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation#Equations_of_Lebesgue%E2%80%93Nagell_type)
- [Densest sphere packing](https://www.math.harvard.edu/media/slipper.pdf)
  Modular forms find the lattice with the densest sphere packing problem in dimensions 8 ([$E_8$ lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_lattice)) and in dimension 24 ([Leech lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leech_lattice)).
- [Ramanujan's constant](https://mathoverflow.net/a/5156/11260)
  Modular forms explain why $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}$ is so close to an integer.

Answer (score 4):

Modular forms are used to solve Fermat's last theorem, Mock modular forms are used in black holes theory. I read also in Quanta magazine that Eisenstein series are used to compute what we call Monster group.
https://d2r55xnwy6nx47.cloudfront.net/uploads/2017/08/symmetry-algebra-and-the-monster-20170817.pdf
Here is an interesting article to see the beautiful application of modular forms in astronomy https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=795545447309716&id=247304225467177

Comment: OP asks for applications in Number Theory. Black holes, Monster group, and astronomy don't qualify.